# Что означает такое преобразование типов

Tags: c#

Что это за запись?

```
// double value 
ulong TmpValue = *(ulong *)&value;
```

В чем отличие от

```
ulong TmpValue = (ulong)value;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во втором варианте преобразования используется округление вещественного числа к целому. [Почитать про обычное округление](https://aakinshin.net/ru/posts/cheatsheet-rounding/)

В первом же варианте используются указатели. Что происходит в этом варианте?

1. Получается адрес в памяти `value`
2. Указатель на `double` приводится к указателю на `ulong`
3. Достаётся значение из места в памяти, где записан `double` так, будто бы там записан `ulong`